# How to use dimension and declare multiple arrays with different size in same line using Fortran?

Tags: fortran

I am given this code:

```
...
IMPLICIT REAL*8(a-h,o-z)
DIMENSION L1(L), L2(M), L3(N)
...
```

I want to use `IMPLICIT NONE` but I don't know how to declare variable type using `DIMENSION` and maintain one line declaration of L1 to L3.
Something like:

```
INTEGER, DIMENSION :: L1(L), L2(M), L3(N) !(this doesn't work)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for the `dimension` statement differs from that of specifying the `dimension` attribute in a declaration statement.

So, whereas

```
dimension i(4) ! Implicitly typed
```

gives `i` array nature of size 4,

```
integer, dimension(4) :: i
```

is the way to go.

Now to come to your question about declaring multiple arrays in one line:

```
integer i(4), j(5), k(6)
```

Finally, one can still use

```
integer, dimension(4) :: i, j(5), k(6), l
```

making `i` and `l` arrays of size 4 and `j` and `k` arrays of size 5 and 6.